# Can I initialize variable in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```py
for col in ws:
    for value in col:
        new_value = value * 2
        blank_list.append(new_value)
```

What should be the list comprehension for this?
I think of it like this, but I don't know what to write after that -

```py
blank_list = [new_value for col in ws for value in col]
```

I don't what to do after this ?

Comment: You should add a language tag. Python, I guess?

Comment: Assuming this is Python, try: `[value * 2 for col in ws for value in col]`

Comment: with >= 3.8 you can use `:=` operator in for ex loops, conditional, lambda, ...

Comment: @cards I know that the following is valid: `[new_value := value * 2 for col in ws for value in col]`, however, in this particular example, assigning the value to `new_value` is not useful at all. I wonder if you have a more useful example?

Comment: @qrsngky in a conditional `d = {"k": 1};
if v:=d.get("k", None):
    print(v); # instead of d["k"]`

Comment: @qrsngky or for recursive patterns `[(j:=i*i)+1/j for i in range(1, 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
blank_list = [value*2 for col in ws for value in col]
```

This will give you the result you're expecting.

Example:

```
ws = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
blank_list = [value*2 for col in ws for value in col] 
print(blank_list)

# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Comment: According to the output, it should be `# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]` rather than `# [[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12]]`

Comment: Fixed the output. Code works correctly. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer for this case is the one given by @sud above.  But for more complicated list comprehensions, you can write:

```
blank_list = [result for col in ws for value in col for result in [value * 2]]
```

Python has an optimization so that looping over a list that is known to be one element is handled as an assignment.  The syntax is a little ugly, but it's useful to know when you need a temporary variable in list comprehension.

Comment: There is no such optimization. I just looked at `dis.dis(lambda: [a for a in [5]])`.

Comment: @user3840170 pretty sure it doesn't apply to the leftmost one, because that is essentially just passed in as an argument to the function (and referenced as the special variable `.0`). Here is the documentation in the changelog for this optimization: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations

Comment: @user3840170 here is the actual issue where it is discussed: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77037

Comment: I didn't even know this, thanks.

Comment: I also tried `dis.dis(lambda: [a*b*c for a in [5] for b in [6] for c in [7]])`. Nothing of the sort happens. (CPython 3.11.2)

Comment: @user3840170.  I wasn't hallucinating.  https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations 
"Optimized the idiom for assignment a temporary variable in comprehensions. Now `for y in [expr]` in comprehensions is as fast as a simple assignment `y = expr`.  ... Unlike the `:=` operator, this idiom does not leak a variable to the outer scope."